# Changing state of one component from another component in another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and web dev in general.
I have created a Component containing list of calculator like buttons which is stored in `Buttons.js`.

There is another component called as Submit stored in `Submit.js`. Submit component is basically a textbox in which we type a mathematical expression which I want to process later.

Both of these components are then called in another component call `Leftwindow.js`.

So my question is,
How can I make clicking in `Buttons` component affect the textbox in `Submit` component. I know it could be done easily had the buttons and input box been the part of a single component.
Basically if I press the '1' button I want it to be added to the input box.

A snapshot of how it looks -

[Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2tXP.png)

Code for `Buttons.js` -

```
class Buttons extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            //buttonrows//
        };
    }

    render(){
        const row1elems = this.state.row1.map((button) => {
            return (
                <Button color={colours[button.type]} className="buttonsize">{button.label}</Button>
            );
    
        });
        const row2elems = this.state.row2.map((button) => {
            return (
                <Button color={colours[button.type]} className="buttonsize">{button.label}</Button>
            );
    
        });
        const row3elems = this.state.row3.map((button) => {
            return (
                <Button color={colours[button.type]} className="buttonsize">{button.label}</Button>
            );
    
        });
        const row4elems = this.state.row4.map((button) => {
            return (
                <Button color={colours[button.type]} className="buttonsize">{button.label}</Button>
            );
    
        });
        return (
            <div className="center">
                <ButtonGroup>
                    {row1elems}
                </ButtonGroup>
                <ButtonGroup>
                    {row2elems}
                </ButtonGroup>
                <ButtonGroup>
                    {row3elems}
                </ButtonGroup>
                <ButtonGroup>
                    {row4elems}
                </ButtonGroup>
            </div>
        );  
    }
}
export default Buttons;
```

Code for `Submit.js` -

```
class Submit extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state =  {
            fx: ''
        }
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        
    }
    handleInputChange(event){
        const target = event.target;
        const val = target.val;
        const name = target.name;
        this.setState({
            [name]: val
        })
    }
    handleSubmit(event){

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <FormGroup row>
                <Col md={12}>
                <Input type="text" id="fx" name="fx" placeholder="Type Here" value = {this.state.fx} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            </Form>
            <Button type="submit" color="primary">Differentiate</Button>
            </div>    
        )
    }
}
export default Submit;
```

Code for `LeftWindow.js` --

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Buttons from './Buttons';
import './Custom.css';
import Submit from './Submit';
class LeftWindow extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="col-3 bg-dark fullheight">
                <Buttons/>
                <h3 className="center">Enter the function to be differentiated</h3>
                <Submit/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default LeftWindow;
```

Comment: You must have included both Components in a single file right? Something Like Calc.js

Comment: Yes, This particular problem could have been solved easily by that. I just intend to have a better understanding of React and javascript in general.

Comment: You didn't get me bro, I'm asking you to share that file in which you've imported both of these components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your common ancestor file will look like -

1. Added state having input.
2. Added a callback "handleInputChange" which updates this input state.
3. Passed this callback to Both the components.

[image]

In your Submit.js file you will need to change your input tag with this

```
<Input 
    type="text"
    value={this.props.input}
    onChange={e => {
        this.props.handleInputChange(e.target.value);
    }}
 />
```

Also in your Buttons.js file call `this.props.handleInputChange` on Button click.

```
<Button
    onClick={() => {
        this.props.handleInputChange(button.label)
    }} 
    color={colours[button.type]} 
    className="buttonsize"
>
    {button.label}
</Button>
```

That's it.

Hope I could help!

Comment: The keyboard input is working fine after the changes but input from the buttons is still not working. This is what i changed in the Button tag -- <Button onClick = {this.props.handleInputChange} color={colours[button.type]} className="buttonsize">{button.label}</Button> . How does the button basically know what it has to pass as the string to be typed exactly?

Comment: You'll need to pass button.label into that handleInputChange Function. I've edited my answer with code.

Answer (score 1):

In React you work with tree of components where data can travel from top to bottom. It is possible to *notify* parent component about changed data via passed callbacks. If you have two components that have common ancestor, you can share data between them through this common ancestor.

Let's say you have component Parent which renders your Buttons and Submit components. If you store your data (or state) in Parent and pass this data as props with callbacks, your components then can notify Parent about things happened and parent can change it's state and pass new state as props to children.

There is a "state management" solutions when your data lives detached of your components and injected on one by one basis. In such you won't need parent to store the data, but if we talk about pure react - to share data between branches in react tree, this branches should have common ancestor somewhere in the tree.

Comment: The branches do have a common ancestor. Please see my edit and let me know what I can do here.

Comment: Put state that you want to share between components to this ancestor and pass it down as props. Add callbacks to change this store and pass it along with data in props. When child will call callback, you update state of the parent and react will provide new  props to children